# Timezone conversion while using select or find query in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, datetime, mongoose

```
select created_at, CONVERT_TZ(created_at, 'UTC', 'IST') as local_created_at 
from posts
WHERE created_at between CONVERT_TZ('01-07-2022 00:00:00','IST','UTC') AND CONVERT_TZ('30-07-2022 23:59:59','IST','UTC').
```

I have stored the data values in UTC in database. Now How will be above the query in mongoose ? Here all the **IST** are the user's timezone (it will be dynamic, based on user's timezone) and the date value (in above example '01-07-2022 00:00:00' and '30-07-2022 23:59:59') is also dynamic. This date value will be provided in the user's current time zone. As example here both 01-07-2022 00:00:00' and '30-07-2022 23:59:59' are provided in IST timezone.

Comment: When you create a `Date` object in Javascript, then it is automatically converted to UTC. It should simply work - provided your date values are properly stored as `Date` objects, not as string.

Comment: Please provide some sample data (as JSON, not as table) and show us what you have tried so fat (again not as SQL, MongoDB is a **NoSQL** database)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.